# How to parse JsonObject List without knowing the key with Gson?

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I'm having a bit trouble with parsing this JsonObject as I don't know the keys that will come and I'm using Gson. Here is an example of the json:

```
"calendar": {
         "201rj5-9": {
                "year": "2015",
                "month": "9",
         },
         "20tfh15-9": {
                "year": "2015",
                "month": "9",
         },
         [...] 
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like a Map, thus you could use a `HashMap` for your `calendar` field:

```
public class Root {
    HashMap<String, Entry> calendar;

    public static class Entry {
        String year, month;
    }
}
```

And just the matching Gson code for completeness:

```
Root root = new Gson().fromJson(json, Root.class);
```